# w3schools modal not working

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

im trying to get this w3 schools modal working for my site but when the button is pressed it wont pop-up at all.
i already have the css linked elswhere.

i got this code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp).

```
      <div className="sec2">


      {/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/}
        <div class="w3-container">
          <h2>W3.CSS Modal</h2>
          <button onclick={document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'} class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
          <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
            <div class="w3-modal-content">
              <div class="w3-container">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
                <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/}


      </div>
```

Comment: i changed the button element to this and i got a style error,any ideas on how to fix this???

Comment: Instead of commenting, just update your question.

Comment: could you put your whole code on codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: unfortunatly im doing this project for my work so i dont think my boss would be too comfortable with sharing the whole thing. however i can tell you that im using create-react-app and all the code that im using for the modal is there, im getting all of my css from the w3schools librairy

Comment: You are completely missing the point of react, and writing bad code for react. I would suggest spending time learning it. Or, post the complete component code that you have put the modal in, and we can show you how to do it the react way.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `onclick` prop expects a function.

You should get what you want by changing the first button to be:

```
<button onclick={() => { document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'}} class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
```

However given that you are working in React, I'd suggest considering using/setting state instead of retrieving and manipulating DOM elements directly.